Derivatives of radical function and power function with fractional index
I would like to ask a question about the derivative of radical function, related to fractional index which we learned in high school. But as a mathematics student, I hope to get a stricter explanation.
Note: I haven’t studied complex analysis, just a little bit basic real analysis.
In secondary school or high school, we were told that a fractional index form with positive bases can be written as radical form, and the indices law holds for positive bases. As a counterexample with nonpositive base:
$$ (-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=(-1)^{\frac{2}{6}}=((-1)^2)^{\frac{1}{6}}=1^{\frac{1}{6}}=1 $$
The first and second equalities use indices law, and they must fail to hold (if they hold, we get a contradiction). Also, we cannot write the left side of the first equality as a third root radical form ($-1$ as radicand, i.e. $ \sqrt[3]{-1} $).
Now, let’s move to calculus. We have the following formula: $$ \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[3]{x}=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}},\quad x\neq 0 $$
We derive such formula by converting the radical form to rational index power form, i.e.
$$ \frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}} $$
My main question is:

If the radical is defined (meaningful) on nonpositive radicand, then for the above derivation of the derivative, how to precisely discuss the condition that $x$ is nonpositive? I remember that we can only convert the radical with positive radicand to index form (like a power function). Then, how about the meaningful radical with nonpositive radicand?

An extended question:

Are the domains of radical function (eg: $\sqrt[3]{x}$) and fractional index power functions (eg: $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $ x^{\frac{2}{6}}$) the same?
I think that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $ x^{\frac{2}{6}}$ are the same for positive $x$, and they aren’t defined for $x<0$. But Desmos gives the same graph and it has the “negative branch”. If they are defined for $x<0$, I think they cannot be the same, because of the reason in the second paragraph above.

That’s all, thanks a lot.
